# Is it possible to make nginx serve file from FCGI?

Tags: html, c, nginx, fastcgi

Is there a way with fcgi/nginx to do when a html page links something like this:

```
<img src="/path/that/not/exist/file.end"/>
```

We don't get the file-information from the file (As it doesn't even exist).
And instead we submit with fcgi "the file" in C code like this:

```
    char *pImTheFile;
    pImTheFile = loadFileIntoRAM();
    submitFileForNGINX (pImTheFile);
```

so nginx can hook it up and treats it as would it be the File it self?

Answer (score 0):

You deal with this as with other virtual files. You use rewrite to pass the request to a handler. Should be plenty examples on the web for this.

Comment: I googled a whole day for it. So if there are so many examples maybe just point me a good one out?:)